# Chrome, Safari do not observe padding when set by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit

When using Chrome 12.0.742.100, contained elements in an element that has `padding-right` set by JavaScript do not update their position accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This webkit bug has been reported for Chromium in May 2011. Until it gets fixed, and in some cases, we could use `margin` attribute instead.
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=81879